# Training a LDA model with gensim from some external tf-idf matrix and term list

Tags: python-3.x, tf-idf, lda, topic-modeling, gensim

I have a tf-idf matrix already, with rows for terms and columns for documents. Now I want to train a LDA model with the given terms-documents matrix. The first step seems to be using `gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus` to convert the matrix into the corpus format. But how to construct the `id2word` parameter? I have the list of the terms (#terms==#rows) but I don't know the format of the dictionary so I cannot construct the dictionary from functions like `gensim.corpora.Dictionary.load_from_text`. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`id2word` must map each id (integer) to term (string).

In other words, it must support `id2word[123] == 'koala'`.

A plain Python `dict` is the easiest option.